# Получить значения из списка кортежей

Tags: python, список

Как мне получить новый список из первых элементов каждого tuple? `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`, пробовал `items[::][0]`, но не работает:(
Исходный список:

```py
items = [
    (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10) 
]
```

Answer (score 3):

например так:

**способ 1:**

```
items = [ (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10) ]

items2 = [v[0] for v in items]
```

**способ 2:**

```
items2 = list(zip(*items))[0]
```

**способ 2.1:**

```
items2 = next(zip(*items))
```

Comment: во втором питоне можно и так ```zip(*items)[0]```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант до кучи:

```
from operator import itemgetter

items = [
    (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10) 
]
result = list(map(itemgetter(0), items))
```